# Failed to allocate memory - What is it trying to say?

Tags: php, memory

In my early days of programming I often used to get memory related fatal errors in the following format:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of <some big number> bytes exhausted 
(tried to allocate <some small number> bytes) in /path/to/filename.php 
on line <some line number>
```

I'm a little embarrassed to state that even though I have figured out how to solve them and take steps to avoid them altogether, I'm still not quite sure what exactly does the message translate to in simple words.

For example, if I get a message such as:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4000 bytes) 
in ........ on line 34
```

As things stand at the moment, I assume it to be stating that the script consumes 67108864 bytes of data, but only 4000 bytes are available during runtime.

- Am I right in my assumption?
- If not, what's the correct interpretation?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has 67108864 bytes (~67MB) available to it at runtime, all of which it has filled. The specific allocation which took the total memory usage from <67MB to >67MB was an allocation of 4000 bytes, which happened within the expression on line 34.

Basically, you're using too much memory, and all the interpreter can give you to help is the specific allocation which broke the camel's back. It could have been a one byte allocation, all that matters is that it took you over your memory limit.

Comment: So if I understood it correctly, it fell short by 4000 bytes? If the runtime memory was 67MB + 4001 bytes, the script would have executed successfully?

Comment: @asprin: No, not necessarily. As soon as your script hits your memory limit, it *stops*. If your runtime memory had an extra 4000 bytes, then it would have passed that line, but then failed on the next allocation. You need to figure out why your script is using so much memory. If it's unavoidable, you need to raise the memory limit, and if it's avoidable, you should avoid it. PHP uses a reference counting garbage collector, so any variable which falls out of scope should be immediately collected (Unless there are reference cycles, which it catches with other techniques later)

Answer (score -4):

67108864 bytes are also known as 64 MiB (Mebibyte).
Many softwares like PHP still identifies 64 MB as 64 MiB, this is an historically grown issue.

Nowaday we define 64 000 000 bytes as 64 MB (Megabyte, 64 * 1000 ^ 2)
and 67108864 bytes as 64 MiB (Mebibyte, 64 * 1024 ^ 2).

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question entirely....